# Refusal to frame embedded website within my web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-security-policy

I am receiving the following error message when viewing the errors within the console on Google Chrome:

Refused to frame 'https://website.com because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

I am accessing this on a third party hosted vm which I Remote on to to access my website which contains the embedded website https://website.com as an example. I have tried accessing this through a separate vm and it works fine, using same version of Chrome etc. Is there anything I need to change within IIS, or the website coding itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `https://website.com` published a Content Security Policy (CSP) with directive: `frame-ancestors 'self'`. This means that this site prohibits embedding itself in frames on all domains except its own.

If you are the owner of the `https://website.com` site, you can add domains to the policy that are allowed to embed the site in frames:

`frame-ancestors 'self' example.com another_allowed_domain.net`

And make sure that the site does not publish the HTTP response header `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`, which acts the same as `frame-ancestors 'self'`.

If you are not the owner of the `https://website.com` site, you can't embed it into `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<embed>` or `<object>` - this is how CSP `frame-ancestors` directive protects web pages from clickjacking.